# Flutter cleaning Xcode workspace taking forever

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

When I run `flutter clean`, it seems to be stuck at the first task `Cleaning Xcode workspace...`. Only after waiting several hours, like 2 or 3 hours (I was literally sleeping during this task) will it succeed and move on. The rest of the task complete pretty quickly, but I don't think it is normal that I have to wait so long for flutter to clean xcode workspace? Any idea what I should do or what is causing this?

I tried cleaning in xcode, **Project** > **Clean Build Folder**, but it does nothihg. I tried restarting my mac, but it also didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Is your app in your iCloud folder?

If yes, try to right click on the root folder then click on download.

Then try flutter clean again.